# Playing videos from Vimeo in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Playing videos from Vimeo in my app

What I would like to do is have my app set up so that when the user taps on a button an action is called to load specific Vimeo video and play it back full screen with the timeline on the top and the playback controls on the bottom, with support for device rotation.

I understand that I could load the video into a UIWebView and have the user tap on the Vimeo supplied 'play' button, but I would really like to be able to start video playback on my own buttonPressed action. Is this possible? If so, is it possible to receive some guidance and maybe some samples to go along with it?

Answer (score 0):

No Its not possible. For play video you will need to press vimeo play button.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible. Assuming you use the video player link (e.g. http://player.vimeo.com/video/59560377) on your own web page, you can drill down to Vimeo player's HTML5 video player and control the buttons. Also, Vimeo provides [JavaScript API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) to control the video.

But seems the Vimeo player has feature detection; it shows its Flash player version even I modified the User Agent to iPhone / iPad, therefore I cannot test my theory.

**UPDATE:** There is no way to force Vimeo player to be in HTML5 mode. ( [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395981/force-vimeo-html5-video-embed) )